# Continue with the attribute to the next requested page

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, servlets

Initially a table full of values are posted, and a column with the drop button is available using javascript coding. When I click the drop button, a dialog pops up with yes or no, if I click yes, I want that specific order to be transferred to another servlet (/drop). This is the order page (/order) with all the orders. How do I move the order from this page (/order) to the drop page (/drop) and delete that specific order from the /order page?
This is what I did, and I get errors.

(/order)

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        if (session.getAttribute("user_name") != null) {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Payroll", "root", " ");
            String userName = (String) session.getAttribute("user_name");
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from Payroll.Order order by delDate asc");

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();


            out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">" 
                    + "function getConfirmation(){"
                    + "var retVal = confirm(\"Add to Drop List?\");"
                    + "if( retVal == true ){"
                    + "document.location=\"DvDrop\";"
                    + "return true;"
                    + "}"
                    + "else{"
                    + "document.location=\"DvOrders\";"
                    + "return false;"
                    + "}"
                    + "}"
                    + "</script>" );

            out.println(<strong>Welcome " + session.getAttribute("user_name") + "</strong>");

            out.println("<br><h2><center><b>Order List</b></center></h2><br><table border=\"1\" style=\"width:100%;border-spacing: 0.5em;text-align: center;\">");
            out.println("<tr><td><b>Order ID</b></td><td><b>Ordered Date</b></td><td><b>Ordered Time</b></td><td><b>Total Amount</b></td><td><b>Delivery Date</b></td><td><b>Add to Drop List</b></td></tr></b>");
            while (rs.next()) {
                out.println("<tr><td><a href = # style=\"width:90%;\">"+ rs.getString(1) + "</a></td><td>" + rs.getString(2) + "</td><td>" + rs.getTime(3) + "</td><td>" + rs.getDouble(4) + "</td><td>" + rs.getDate(5) + "</td>");
                out.println("<td>" + "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Add to Drop\" name=\"AddDrop\" onClick=\"getConfirmation()\">" + "</td></tr>");
            }
            out.println("</table>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?id=Your session may be expired. You have to login first");

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println(e);
    }
}
```

(/drop)

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        // PrintWriter out = response.getWriter() ;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        if (session.getAttribute("user_name") != null) {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Payroll", "root", " ");
            String userName = (String) session.getAttribute("user_name");
            String order = (String)session.getAttribute("Orderid");
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("delete * from Payroll.Order where Orderid = '" + order + "'");

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're getting Java compilation errors in your code. If your code for `/order` servlet is the same as you've posted here, then, in your code's

```
out.println(<strong>Welcome " + session.getAttribute("user_name") + "</strong>");
```

there's an error. You have not defined the string correctly for HTML to be sent to the browser. You need to use a `double quotes` before the `<strong>` tag, which seems to be causing the `Illegal start of expression` error

Try this.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    if (session.getAttribute("user_name") != null) {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Payroll", "root", " ");
        String userName = (String) session.getAttribute("user_name");
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from Payroll.Order order by delDate asc");

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();


        out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">" 
                + "function getConfirmation(id){"
                + "var retVal = confirm(\"Add to Drop List?\");"
                + "if( retVal == true ){"
                + "document.location=\"DvDrop?Orderid=" + id + "\";"
                + "return true;"
                + "}"
                + "else{"
                + "document.location=\"DvOrders\";"
                + "return false;"
                + "}"
                + "}"
                + "</script>" );

        out.println("<strong>Welcome " + session.getAttribute("user_name") + "</strong>");

        out.println("<br><h2><center><b>Order List</b></center></h2><br><table border=\"1\" style=\"width:100%;border-spacing: 0.5em;text-align: center;\">");
        out.println("<tr><td><b>Order ID</b></td><td><b>Ordered Date</b></td><td><b>Ordered Time</b></td><td><b>Total Amount</b></td><td><b>Delivery Date</b></td><td><b>Add to Drop List</b></td></tr></b>");
        while (rs.next()) {
            out.println("<tr><td><a href = # style=\"width:90%;\">"+ rs.getString(1) + "</a></td><td>" + rs.getString(2) + "</td><td>" + rs.getTime(3) + "</td><td>" + rs.getDouble(4) + "</td><td>" + rs.getDate(5) + "</td>");
            out.println("<td>" + "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Add to Drop\" name=\"AddDrop\" onClick=\"getConfirmation(\'" + rs.getString(1) + "\')\" />" + "</td></tr>");
        }
        out.println("</table>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?id=Your session may be expired. You have to login first");

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    out.println(e);
}
```

Here, since you need to add a specific item to the drop list, I would suggest creating the button in such a way that when you click it, it sends the ID of the order to be dropped. The proposed change has been made in the above code. What I'm doing there is sending the current order's ID as an argument to the function `getConfirmation()`. If you want, you can see the final HTML content that is generated using your browser's inspect tool. You'll see that each button calls the same function, but with the corresponding order ID

Also, in your `/drop` servlet, you're trying to perform data manipulation (insert/update/delete), but you're using the `executeQuery()` method for it. Instead, try using the `executeUpdate()`, something like this

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
try {
    // PrintWriter out = response.getWriter() ;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    if (session.getAttribute("user_name") != null) {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Payroll", "root", " ");
        String userName = (String) session.getAttribute("user_name");
        //String order = (String)session.getAttribute("Orderid");
        String order = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Orderid"));
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("delete * from Payroll.Order where Orderid = '" + order + "'");

        int rs = ps.executeUpdate();

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    out.println(e);
}
```

Apart from this, in your JavaScript code, you're assigning a new location to the window, and immediately after that, you're trying to return something. The moment you assign a new location to the document, the current script ends there, and the new web page's script starts executing.

I've proposed some changes to your JavaScript code as well. They're in the first code snippet. Hope this helps!

Cheers!

Comment: `out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">" 
+ "function getConfirmation(id){"
+ "var retVal = confirm(\"Add to Drop List?\");"
 + "if( retVal == true ){"
                + "document.location=\"DvDrop?Orderid=" + **id** + "\";"
                + "return true;"
                + "}"
                + "else{"
                + "document.location=\"DvOrders\";"`
                

 I get an error because of the id, its underlined in red in the code...

Comment: Just remove the Double Quotes around the `id` variable. Right now, the code understands that `id` is a Java variable that needs to be appended to a string. When you remove the Double Quotes around it, it will be used as a variable value that can be accessed by JavaScript, whereas for Java, it's just another part of the string